# Submitting a form with an aviary edited image

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, aviary

I'm trying to use aviary to edit photo's in my ruby on rails app. I have a form where user's can edit their profile, on this they have the option to keep their current image, edit it with aviary or upload a new one. Aviary provides a temporary link to the new edited image, I want this edited image to not be sent to the server until the whole form is submitted. How should i go about doing this?

I had hoped to pass the url into the input file path but from looking taking a look at what firefox sens back it says it is an unsafe operation. Also does the filepath for the input file have to be a local one?

in html in my form:

```
<div id="testInput" >  </div>
```

in aviary's onSave

```
$('<input type="file" id="photo_1" name="photo_1">').appendTo('#testInput');
  var imgFile = document.getElementById("photo_1");
  imgFile.value = newURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude have you tried CarrierWave gem? I'm going to try it on tomorrow... it has a helper called `remote_(file)_url` that asks for an image url. Anyway, you can read about this [here, on its github](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location)

hope I can help you